# How to connect 2 callers together with Twilio

Tags: twilio, voip

I have a situation where I want to anonymously connect 2 callers together. The idea being, you call a phone number enter a digit (each digit corresponds to another phone number) Once you enter in your digits the phone calls the other phone number and then once that other phone number picks up, the two callers are connected.

How would I do this as cheap as possible? Is there a way to do it on Twilio to connect the 2 calls, but then once the calls are connected to not have to go through Twilio anymore?

Comment: Also, does anyone know of a way to anonymously connect 2 callers together, for as cheap as possible? (Doesn't need to be through twilio)

Answer (score 4):

This is possible using Twilio. The first party calls a Twilio number which then uses the [`<Dial>` TwiML verb](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/2010-04-01/twiml/dial) to call the second party, using the [`callerId` attribute](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-caller-id) to anonymize who the call is from. For that attribute value you can use any number you have purchased from Twilio or is a validated outgoing caller ID on your account.

Generally what people do in this case is give everyone who needs to make anonymized calls their own phone number. Then you show use that for the caller ID so if the second party calls the number back, they'd also be anonymously forwarded as well.

In this case you'd be charged 1 cent per minute for the duration of the incoming call initiated by the first party, and 2 cents per minute for the duration of the leg connecting the second party.

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly certain, that if you connect thru twilio, you stay connected (and incur per-minute charges) during the entire conversation.

Openvbx, which is built on twilio, does a similar thing, where you can initiate a call from the web, it calls you at your 'real' phone, you press a key and then it connects the second caller. Charges apply during the connection.

(I realize this doesn't answer the first part of the question, just answering the charge-related part)

Comment: Thanks, yea... I wasn't exactly sure on the charges. But I figured that was the case. I know OpenVBX can do that basic thing.. The application I need is a little more advanced, but basically the same functional concept. I'll have to think of another clever way

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty basic Twilio function:

1. First call, respond with twiml using  to get the digits, and providing a url where to send the digits to
2. Respond to the request with digits using a  verb with  to call and, like John said, set the caller ID to something else (like another twilio inbound number).
3. When the other party picks up, the call is connected.

Pricing-wise, you's be looking at approximately 3 cents per minute or 5 cents if a toll-free number is used.

With Twilio, you will not be able to connect the two calls and then "not use" Twilio. This is an all or nothing proposition, unless you get one of the users to re-dial the call directly.

Only alternative I can thing of, that would not require paying Twilio requires you setting up your own routing setup, such as Asterisk box. However, the cost associated with doing this is arguably greater - you have to learn telco stuff and get a decent rate on minutes from a voip carrier, not to mention supporting it. On the upside, you control your own routing here and you can get better rates, such as $0.0127 per minute here: http://www.minutehub.com/ (I have never used them and am not affiliated with them)

I've worked now in several companies using Twilio in production and have nothing but good experience with them. If you are just starting out, these guys let you focus on the problem you are solving first. Once your solution is baked, you can focus on optimizing the costs. Good luck!

Comment: Can't you just use a raspberry pi with asterisk software?